# How to get a resources path after jlink-ing?

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, javafx, jlink

I am trying to make my JavaFx-Application executable using Maven and Visual Studio Code.

After some time spent on this topic, I found some posts mentioning jlink.

I am a newcomer when it comes to packaging Java/JavaFX applications, so I gave it a try.

Currently, I can at least execute the launcher for the package.

But immediately after starting the application, a NullPointerException is thrown:
**Cannot invoke "Object.toString()" because the return value of "java.lang.Class.getResource(String)" is null.**

For styling the components of my view I created some .css-files and put them inside a /style directory. This directory I placed this, according to the sample JavaFx application, inside a /resources directory created by Maven. In a similar manner, I proceeded with my sound and image files.

Here you can see an excerpt of my directory structure.

```
|
|--src/main
|  |
|  |-- java
|  |   | ...
|  |
|  |-- resources
|      |
|      |-- img
|      |   | ...    
|      |
|      |-- style
|      |   | ...
|      |
|      |-- sound
|          | ...
|
|-- target
    |
    |-- classes
    |   | ...
    |   |
    |   |-- img
    |   |   | ...
    |   |
    |   |-- style
    |   |   | ...
    |   |
    |   |-- sound
    |   |   | ...
    |
    |-- ...
    |
    |-- app
        |
        |-- bin
        |-- ...
```

Now I am trying to access my resources from within my application.

This was my first approach. It works just fine when running from VSCode.

```
    public static final String PATH_TO_STYLESHEET = App.class.getResource("/style").toString();
    public static final String PATH_TO_IMG = App.class.getResource("/img").toString();
    public static final String PATH_TO_SOUNDS = App.class.getResource("/sounds").toString();
```

But after running jlink, my application crashes, showing the NullPointerException mentioned earlier.

Here is my pom.xml:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>App</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>19</maven.compiler.release>
        <javafx.version>19</javafx.version>
        <javafx.maven.plugin.version>0.0.8</javafx.maven.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${javafx.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
                    <jlinkImageName>App</jlinkImageName>
                    <launcher>launcher</launcher>
                    <mainClass>com.test.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
    
</project>
```

And this is the command I have been using for creating the package.

`mvn javafx:jlink -f pom.xml`

Does anyone have an idea how I can get the path to my stylesheets, images, and sounds, after running jlink? The path is absolutely sufficient. I do not need a file itself.

Is there an option to copy the resources to a specific location?

Comment: What you have that works pre-`jlink` should "just work" post-`jlink` as well. Seems like your resources are being packaged incorrectly. Could you show your `pom.xml` file and the exact commands you use to create your custom run-time image (step-by-step)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problem

You have code such as the following:

> ```java
> public static final String PATH_TO_IMG = App.class.getResource("/img").toString();
> ```

This is trying to get the resource `"/img"`. But according to your question, that is not a resource *per se*, but instead a directory (i.e., a package). And the problem appears to be the inconsistent behavior of `Class#getResource(String)` when the `String` argument denotes a directory. When your code is *not* in a JRT image then the call to `#getResource(String)` will return a `URL`; when your code *is* packaged in a JRT image then the same call will return `null`, despite the fact the directory exists.

I don't know if this behavior is a bug or simply undefined. One interesting thing is [`ModuleReader#find(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/module/ModuleReader.html#find(java.lang.String)) clearly is *capable* of finding directories:

> Finds a resource, returning a URI to the resource in the module.
>
> If the module reader can determine that the name locates a directory then the resulting URI will end with a slash (`'/'`).

That indicates, to me at least, that what you're trying to do should be possible. But even that method fails when the module is packaged in a JRT image (by returning an empty `Optional`). Note that if you query the [`ModuleReader#list()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/module/ModuleReader.html#list()) method it will include directories when the module is **not** in a JRT image, but those same directories are not included when the module **is** in a JRT image.

### Example

I've put a minimal example demonstrating this problem at the end of this answer.

---

## A Solution

I assume you're using these constants (e.g., `PATH_TO_IMG`) to do stuff like the following:

```java
Image image = new Image(PATH_TO_IMG + "foo.png");
```

Which avoids having calls to `SomeClass.class.getResource("...").toString()` everywhere. If this is your goal, then I can think of at least one solution. Change your constants to simply reference the *resource root*. For example:

```java
public static final String IMG_ROOT = "/img";
```

Then create a utility method to resolve the resource:

```java
public static String getImagePath(String name) {
    var resource = IMG_ROOT + "/" + name;
    var url = App.class.getResource(resource);
    if (url == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("could not find resource: " + resource);
    }
    return url.toString();
}
```

And then you can use that utility method like so:

```java
Image image = new Image(getImagePath("foo.png"));
```

#### Possible Alternative

Another option might be to make use of the JRT `FileSystem` implementation. Something like the following:

```java
FileSystem jrtFs = FileSystems.getFileSystem(URI.create("jrt:/"));
Path path = jrtFs.getPath("modules", "<module-name>", "img");
// Note: Doesn't seem to include the trailing '/'
String pathToImg = path.toUri().toString();
```

Though you'll have to detect if your code is in a JRT image or not.

---

## Minimal Example

Given this doesn't have to do with JavaFX specifically, I've created a minimal example to demonstrate this problem.

- Maven 3.8.6
- OpenJDK 19.0.1 2022-10-18
- Tested on Windows 11

### Source Code

##### Project structure:

```
|   pom.xml
|
\---src
    \---main
        +---java
        |   |   module-info.java
        |   |
        |   \---sample
        |           Main.java
        |
        \---resources
            \---data
                    file.txt
```

##### pom.xml:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>19</maven.compiler.release>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jlink-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <launcher>app=app/sample.Main</launcher>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

##### module-info.java:

```java
module app {}
```

##### Main.java:

```java
package sample;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var modRef = Main.class.getModule()
            .getLayer()
            .configuration()
            .findModule(Main.class.getModule().getName())
            .orElseThrow()
            .reference();
        System.out.printf("Module Location = %s%n%n", modRef.location().orElseThrow());

        var dataUrl = Main.class.getResource("/data");
        var fileUrl = Main.class.getResource("/data/file.txt");
        System.out.printf("Data URL = %s%nFile URL = %s%n%n", dataUrl, fileUrl);
    }
}
```

### Building

I ran these two commands to build the project:

1. `mvn compile jar:jar`
2. `mvn jlink:jlink`

For whatever reason, doing `mvn compile jar:jar jlink:jlink` caused the `jlink` task to fail.

### Output

And here is the different output for the different packaging:

##### Exploded module:

```
...> java -p target\classes -m app/sample.Main
Module Location = file:///C:/Users/***/Desktop/jlink-tests/target/classes/

Data URL = file:/C:/Users/***/Desktop/jlink-tests/target/classes/data/
File URL = file:/C:/Users/***/Desktop/jlink-tests/target/classes/data/file.txt
```

##### Modular JAR:

```
...> java -p target\app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -m app/sample.Main
Module Location = file:///C:/Users/***/Desktop/jlink-tests/target/app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Data URL = jar:file:///C:/Users/***/Desktop/jlink-tests/target/app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/data/
File URL = jar:file:///C:/Users/***/Desktop/jlink-tests/target/app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/data/file.txt
```

##### JRT Image:

```
...> .\target\maven-jlink\default\bin\app
Module Location = jrt:/app

Data URL = null
File URL = jrt:/app/data/file.txt
```

### Results

As you can see, the call to `getResource("/data/file.txt")` worked every time, but the call to `getResource("/data")` did not work for the JRT-packaged version.

Comment: *...Whether or not calling getResource with a path to a package is supposed to work...*
No problem about that.

Comment: Could you please clarify? Because from my testing, that is exactly the problem. Same code, same resources on the module-path, yet it works when _not_ in a JRT but fails when _in_ a JRT.

Comment: that's how I load resources (getClass().getResource()) and I haven't noticed any problems with that.

Comment: @mrmcwolf Edited my answer a bit. Added a minimal example to demonstrate that trying to get a directory with `getResource` when the module is packaged in a JRT image does not appear to work.

Comment: as a matter of fact, I've never tried loading a directory as a resource. I didn't even think this was possible until your post :(

Comment: interesting digging, same as @mrmcwolf I didn't even know this is possible :) Suspect, though, that the question is - at least near to -  a xy-problem: the path-string -> url -> url-string mapping storage for later use to do whatever (code not shown by the asker) smells like incorrect resource lookup